# Ember route or controller expose data model as json

Tags: javascript, json, model-view-controller, ember.js

I am trying to work with Ember.js

Can I expose my data model as JSON through a route or controller?

I have an object like this saved in the store:

```
this.store.createRecord('Person', {
  id: 1,
  name: this.get('name'),
  email: this.get('email')
});
```

I want to expose this data from a route or controller as JSON object. I don't want to use any view.

Is it possible to do this?
Thanks for help!

EDIT
My route is:

```
App.ResultRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() { 
   return this.store.find('person', 1);
   }
});
```

There is '1' because I want only this record.
In this way It works and I see in the view the {{name}} and the {{email} of the Person object.
I want to see only the JSON, I tried to do how you suggest me :

```
App.ResultRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  afterModel: function (model) {
  model.get('content').forEach(function (item) {
    console.log(item.get('content'));
   });
 } 
});
```

But I receive this error:

**Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Error: More context objects were passed than there are dynamic segments for the route: error**

What is my error?

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do this would be, I would have an api in my model which would return a plain json object to whoever asked it. So the `Person` model would have a `getPersonDetails` method which will hide all the internal details, including the attributes and associations and whatever else, and return the state of the `person` object it is invoked upon. 
So, for example, if you wanted to display a table of persons or something, you would do a createRecord, and just ask the newly created `person` object for it's details.

Answer (score 0):

Start from the beginning of this guide. http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/ It will show you how to specify a model for a route.

Then, read this entire guide on controllers: http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/

In general, you would access that data from the route's `model` hook with:

```
this.store.find('person') // All records
```

If you wanted to access that first object as JSON, you could do:

```
var person_JSON = this.store.find('person').then(function (persons) {
  //The persons records are now available so you can do whatever you want with them
  console.log(persons.objectAt(0).get('content'));
});
```

You could also iterate over all records and strip out the content to produce raw json without the Ember wrapping... Just depends on what you need to really do.

Really the best place to put this would be the route's `afterModel` hook, though. You wouldn't be working with a promise, as Ember would have dealt with that for you:

```
afterModel: function (model) {
  model.get('content').forEach(function (item) {
    console.log(item.get('content'));
  });
}
```

Hope that helps.

Edit: Since you have one record try this:

```
afterModel: function (model) {
  console.log(model.get('content'));
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, always the same error. I have a doubt, can Ember expose data model in JSON? I have this record (Person whit name and mail) and I want that may route 'result' return this object as JSON. Can i do this??